# C# Windows Forms Data Grid View Cell Click unsure of data types

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I'm relatively new to coding so I wasn't sure how to word my question very well but I am working on a database and I am not sure what the correct lines of code to use are for each of my datatypes (I have temporarily added the line of code that would be used for a string just to fill in the space to create the error). I have included my code and a screenshot of the errors. Hoping someone understands what I mean and is able to help me out. Thank you.

My Code:

[image: My code (probably not the best)]
[image: Error messages currently displaying]

I tried creating a question previously but I was in a rush as I was in class and it wasn't very clear at all so I hope this is somewhat better and someone is able to properly understand it.

I tried changing the "ToString" section to "ToDateTime" hoping maybe it was a simple fix but still not luck.

Edit: Added my code as text

private void DgvPayment_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

```
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)

        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.DgvPayment.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            selectedPaymentID = (int)row.Cells[0].Value;
            DatePaid = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            TxtAmountPaid.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            TxtPaymentDescription.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            BookingID = (int)row.Cells[4].Value();
            CustomerID = (int)row.Cells[5].Value();
        }
```

Comment: First, you must paste code as text here, not a picture of your code.  There are many reasons for this.  Second, we do not know how the data was added to the DGV.  If yuou used a datasource, the actual datatype is preserved and you simply need to cast.  But you could have done something dumb like change everything to string in which case...well, dont do that

Comment: Hi, sorry I have added my code to the post as text and yes I added my my data to the DGV as a datasource. You said about casting it, It's probably easy but how would I go about doing that? Thanks

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Sorry I think I'm supposed to mention you

Comment: A better path is to set the DataSource of the DataGridView to your data in tangent with a BindingSource and SortableBindingList. This way there is no need to access cells but instead the actual data as [shown here](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/q-a-questions/tree/master/BasicReadWriteJson).

Answer (score 0):

The errors you show are fairly clear.  The first error the compiler is complaining about on the line…

```
DatePaid = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

The compiler is complaining because the compiler does NOT know what `DatePaid` is. Where is `DatePaid` defined and what type is `DatePaid`? The name of the variable implies the variable is a `DateTime` object, however, this is unknown and defining the variable as a `string` should at least get rid of the error.

The compiler is complaining about `BookingID` and `CustomerID` for the same reason. It does not know what `BookingID` or `CustomerID` is... so you need to define those variables.

And lastly, the compiler is complaining about a “non-invocable” member is being used like a method. This error is coming from…

```
Value()
```

In the line of code…

```
(int)row.Cells[4].Value();
```

`Value` is a property… not a method, so you need to remove the “()” as it is shown on the second line of code.…

```
selectedPaymentID = (int)row.Cells[0].Value;
```

Something like below should get rid of the current errors you have shown…

```
int selectedPaymentID;
string DatePaid;
int BookingID;
int CustomerID;

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
    DataGridViewRow row = this.DgvPayment.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    selectedPaymentID = (int)row.Cells[0].Value;
    DatePaid = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    TxtAmountPaid.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    TxtPaymentDescription.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    BookingID = (int)row.Cells[4].Value;
    CustomerID = (int)row.Cells[5].Value;
  }
}
```